# MySQL installation/configuration error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install the MySQL server, but unfortunelly after seting the user configuration (password), I get a message saying "unnable to configure service". I don't have any idea of what might be happening, because I really thought that it would be something more easy to acomplish.
Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: You are much more likely to get a useful answer on http://serverfault.com/ than you are here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed!

The error was: 1045

OS: Windows 7

Actually, there was a folder that should be deleted in the directory ProgramData (wich might be hidden - in C).

So each time I had uninstalled and installed MySQL the same problem had occurred, because that folder was not deleted.

So, to make things right, you have to delete the two MySQL folders in:

C/Program Files;

C/Program Data.

Daniel